# Getting multiple fadeToggle w/ same class name to work independently

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, toggle

I've tried to make a profile with a fadeToggle effect that works via clicking on a trigger/button. It works on the first profile on the page, but every other profile after it refuses to fadeToggle. Due to the way profiles are set up on the site software I'm not able to give these profiles unique classes to fix the problem.

Is there a way for the fadeToggle onclick to work on each profile independently despite having the same class names?

Here's a JSFiddle to demonstrate: https://jsfiddle.net/frustratedkij/vntsjhmg/14/

My javascript:

```
 $( "#prof__trigger" ).click(function() { $( "#sunderav" ).fadeToggle(900, "linear").unbind("click", handler); return false; });
```

HTML:

```
      <div class="sunderminiprof"><div id="sunderav"><img src="img"></img></div>
  <div class="sunderminititle">
    <div class="sundergif"><img src="img"></div>
    <h1>Player</h1><hr><h2><title>Bacon ipsum dolor amet strip steak swine brisket biltong hamburger shank bacon pastrami beef ribs.</title></h2></div>
  <br>
  <br>
  <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">Class</th>
          <th scope="col">House</th>
          <th scope="col">Nation</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">Class here.</th>
          <td>House here.</td>
          <td>Nation here</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">Numbers</th>
          <td>Numbers</td>
          <td>Numbers</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">Numbers</th>
          <td>Numbers</td>
          <td>Numbers</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">Numbers</th>
          <td>Number</td>
          <td>Numbers</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>

<div id="prof__trigger" title="Click for profile"><i class="fa fa-circle"></i></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are now using ID's (of which there should only be one in the document), where you want to use classes, change the #prof__trigger and #sunderav to classes in your html.

What you can do is the following, it would require a small change in the, html and javascript for this to work.

Let's start with the HTML

**HTML**

```
<div class="sunderminiprof">
    <div class="sunderav></div>
    <div class="sunderminititle">
        <div class="sundergif">
            <img src="imgname.*" />
        </div>
        <h1>Player</h1>
        <!-- also add all the other items //-->
    </div>
    <table>
        <!-- add all the table contents //-->
    </table>
    <div class="prof__trigger">
       <i class="fa fa-circle"></i>
    </div>
</div>
```

as before, the prof__trigger is nested in your sunderminiprof. In my previous example, i had the nesting wrong, so what you should try to do is the following. I would personally start with the sunderminiprof element to attach the events on, like so:

**javascript** (using jQuery)

```
var r_miniprofs = $('.sunderminiprof');
$(r_miniprofs).each(function(i, oProf){
    // find all the triggers and sunderav's in this profile.
    r_triggers = $(oProf).find('.prof__trigger');
    r_sunderav = $(oProf).find('.sunderav');

    //loop through the triggers in this profile and attach click event to them.
    //on click, do something with all of the sunderav items in the same profile.
    $(r_triggers).each(function(i, oTrigger){
        $(oTrigger).on('click',function(){
           $(r_sunderav).each(function(i,oSunderav){
               $(oSunderav).fadeToggle(900,'linear')
                           .unbind('click',handler);
           });
           // if your intention was to remove the click from the element, after the profile is revealed, remove the .unbind('click',handler); and add this next bit of code instead of this comment: 
           // $(oTrigger).off();
           return false;
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Doesn't appear to be working, or I've made another mistake. https://jsfiddle.net/frustratedkij/4mLe7cr9/

Comment: that's because your prof__trigger element does not contain anything, you close it directly after you declare it. Meaning that the .sunderNav element, which we are trying to find in .prof__trigger cannot ever be found, since .sunderNav is not a child of .prof__trigger

Comment: I apologize but I'm lost. For the method you're talking about will it still work by clicking a specific trigger, like <div id="prof__trigger" title="Click for profile"><i class="fa fa-circle"></i></div> where the font awesome icon is the trigger? I'm missing how to rearrange the HTML to accomplish this.